# PHP While loop stopped after displaying only one product in MySql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

This php while loop is intended to display information about products stored in MySql database. The while loop is supposed to display the ENTIRE PRODUCTS in the database in bootstrap cards. "Fabric Used" and "Tailor" for each product are stored in separate tables in the database. The tables are connected with foreign keys. Why did the loop stop after displaying only one product AND how do i fix this?

```
<div class="row" id="result">
<?php 
$query ="SELECT * FROM products, tailor_details";
$result=$dbcon->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">         
        <div class="card-deck">      
            <div class="card border-secondary">     
                <img src="<?= $row['Picture'] ?>" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="text light bg-info text-center rounded p-1"><?= $row['Name']; ?></h6>
                    <h4 class="card-title text-danger">Price: <?= number_format($row['Price']); ?>/-
                    </h4>
                    <p>Weight: <?= $row['Weight']; ?><br>Tailor: 

<?php 
    $tailor=$row['Tailor'];
    $getTailor="SELECT biz_name 
                FROM tailor_details 
                WHERE user_id=$tailor";
    $res=$dbcon->query($getTailor);
    while($rw = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['biz_name'];
     } 
?>  
    <br>
     Fabric Used: 
<?php 
    $fabric=$row['Fabric'];
    $getfabric="SELECT FabricName FROM fabrics WHERE FabricsId=$fabric";
    $result=$dbcon->query($getfabric);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['FabricName'];
    } 
?>
   </p>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Customize</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php  
} // endwhile
?>
</div>
```

“I expected the while loop to display every single product and its details in bootstrap cards, just like seen in ecommerce sites;  but the actual output I got is just one product and the loop stopped!.”

See database schema below:

products table

[image]

fabrics table

[image]

tailor_detals table

[image]

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRzcK.jpg)

Comment: Try to format better yuor code. I do not understand where the first while loop ends

Comment: Is while($rw correct ?

Comment: `while($rw = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        echo $row['biz_name'];
     }` shouldn't that be `echo $rw['biz_name']`

Comment: Do you really need `tailor_details` on this query `$query ="SELECT * FROM products, tailor_details";` as you later query the `tailor_details` table seperately

Comment: @Rambarun Komaljeet: Thanks. I've changed it to while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){ echo $row['biz_name']; } but immediately after doing that, i get this error "Fabric Used:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\myareataylor\search-results.php on line 186". And still only one product displayed.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: i have removed tailor_details. Problem persists. New error message when i corrected $rw to $row. see error message: "Fabric Used: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\myareataylor\search-results.php on line 186"

Comment: @Giacomo Masseroni Chiaro: Check the last three lines...you will see the end of the first loop

Comment: @codes4life if you get boolean value from fecth_assoc it means you have error in the query (the function returns false)

Comment: If you showed us that database schema for these 3 tables I would bet these 3 queries could be amalgamated into one

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is right. You can make this query in just one. In the way you are doing it, you set the first query (the one for the while) in the variable $result, and the last query (the one for the fabric) uses this same variable $result, so modifyes it inside the while loop, so you lose all results you had before

Comment: @Giacomo Masseroni Chiaro: Ok Sir. What do you suggest i do now?

Comment: @RiggsFolly: I have added the db schema in the question. Please check again and almalgamate code. That will make my day sir. Thanks

Comment: @nacho: i have changed those variable names...problem remains unsolved...still one product showing with error code: "Fabric Used: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\myareataylor\search-results.php on line 186"

Comment: "Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean" can be searched for on Stack Overflow - it means that the object on which you are calling that method did not instantiate properly, and you got a `false` bool instead of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a lot of peolpe told you in their comments, you don't need three queries, you can do it just with one query. I have changed your code to use only one query:

```
<div class="row" id="result">
<?php 
$query ="SELECT picture,`Name`,price, biz_name,FabricName FROM products a join tailor_details b on a.Tailor=b.user_id join fabrics c on c.FabricsId=a.Fabric";
$result=$dbcon->query($query);
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-2">         
            <div class="card-deck">      
                <div class="card border-secondary">     
                    <img src="<?= $row['Picture'] ?>" class="card-img-top">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="text light bg-info text-center rounded p-1"><?= $row['Name']; ?></h6>
                        <h4 class="card-title text-danger">Price: <?= number_format($row['Price']); ?>/-
                        </h4>
                        <p>Weight: <?= $row['Weight']; ?><br>Tailor: 

    <?php 
        echo $row['biz_name'];
    ?>  
        <br>
        Fabric Used: 
    <?php 
        echo $row['FabricName'];
    ?>
       </p>

                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Customize</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php  
} // endwhile
?>
</div>
```